# И в продложение вопроса

Tags: этимология

И по ассоциации вспомнилось еще слово с неясной мне этимологией "ерунда". Это русское слово?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ЕРУНДА. Искон. В рус. лит. яз. вошло в XIX в. из арго семинаристов, где первоначальное герунда возникло на базе лат. gerundium "герундий". Герундий — одна из трудно усваиваемых чужих (ср. чушь) грамматических форм. См. галиматья.

Яндекс.Словари › Этимологический словарь, 2004

*Словарь Фасмера*: *Ерунда* Ближайшая этимология: (Тургенев, Лесков), Ерундить. Следует объяснять как слово семинарского языка, из лат. gerundium; см. Зеленин, РФВ 54, 115 и сл.; Грот, Фил. Раз. 2, 293. Ср. у Лескова ("Соборяне" 423) указание на книжное происхождение слова, а также на форму Герунда. Отсюда Ерундистика по аналогии Статистика и под.